handheld scanner -> write each scanresult to an own file
I need to write the scanned information (e.g. barcode etc.) from a handheld-scanner directly to a new file - just like flatbed scanners do - without interaction, without saving manually.
So the file won't exist before, there is no chance in creating and opening it for overtaking the scanresult.
I have a Datalogic handheld-scanner and have tried the "Aladdin" Software-Suite but could not find a solution so far - there is no option for saving the result as a file.
Actually I expected the scanner being able to work like a flatbed scanner that can save the scan to a file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
